# SonarQube Rule plsql:QuotedIdentifiersCheck fails

Tags: plsql, sonarqube

This SonarQube rule checks that Quoted identifiers are not used.
But SQL syntax requires quotes when column alias is composed with a space.

Agree with the rule when developers create such variable:

```
"hello" VARCHAR2(42) := 'world';
```

but disagree for that:

```
Select myColA as "Column A",
       myColB as "column B", 
       ...
```

Sonar should not hit for alias in Select statement.

Correct ?

Comment: Salut M. Séb! Yes d'accord avec toi ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems reasonable. [This improvement](https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONARPLSQL-645) should be included in the next version of SonarPLSQL.